# group by Datatable and combine data

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable like this.
[image]

if Datacolumn  "Dept." and "Section" are same.
I want to combine Data.

like this.

[image]

How do to ?

I try:

```
var temp = (from x in workTable.AsEnumerable()
               group x by new
             {
            DepartmentID = x.Field<string>("DepartmentID"),
                                     SectionID = x.Field<string>("SectionID")
                                 } into g
                                 select g  
                                 ).ToList();
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: It will become one data,but  second  data  is missing.

Comment: it won't happen  different rows have intersecting values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following loop to merge those rows:

```
var depSectGroups = workTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new {DepartmentID = row.Field<string>("DepartmentID"), SectionID = row.Field<string>("SectionID")});

DataTable resultTable = workTable.Clone();
foreach (var rowGroup in depSectGroups)
{
    if (rowGroup.Count() == 1)
        resultTable.ImportRow(rowGroup.First());
    else
    {
        DataRow addedRow = resultTable.Rows.Add();
        foreach (DataRow row in rowGroup)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
            {
                if (addedRow.IsNull(col.ColumnName) && !row.IsNull(col))
                    addedRow[col.ColumnName] = row[col];
            }
        }
    }
}
```